# Domain of d.e , Region plot

Tags: differential-equations

$$y^{2/3}+(y')^{2/3}=b^{2/3}.$$
This is d.e which solving with parametres. I want frist find and Plot Domain of this D.E with help manipulate for b.

When i transformate this d.e in explicit shape, i get $y'=\sqrt{b^2-3(by)^{2/3}(b^{2/3}-y^{2/3})-y^2}$ , so domain is for $b^2-3(by)^{2/3}(b^{2/3}-y^{2/3})-y^2>0$. I want now to ManipulatePlot this with mathematica

```
    Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  b^2 - 3 (b*y)^(2/3) (b^(2/3) - y^(2/3)) - y^2 > 0, {x, -3, 
   3}, {y, -3, 10}, Axes -> True], {b, 0, 10}]
```

and i get [image]

If i try to plot this on some other onnline platforms, i will get $y \in (-b,b)$ m not like Mathematica show me here $y \in (0,b)$. It's clear that Mathematica also give some error.

Now, when i start solving this

```
  DSolve[y[x]^(2/3) + y'[x]^(2/3) == b^(2/3), y[x], x]
{{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[-3 ArcTan[#1^(1/3)/Sqrt[b^(2/3) - #1^(2/3)]] + (
       3 #1^(1/3))/Sqrt[b^(2/3) - #1^(2/3)] &][x + C[1]]}}
```

I get GENERAL SOLUTION in shape of InverseFunction which i cant Plot.

If i start to solve this analitic way (manually) i get next.

First we get parametrisation, parametar $u$, that $$ y'=b (\sin{(u)})^3, y=b (\cos{(u)})^3 , u \in [0,\pi] .$$

How is $dy=-3b (\cos{(u)})^2 \sin{(u)} du $ , from $dy=y'dx$, we get $$ -3b (\cos{(u)})^2 \sin{(u)} du=b (\sin{(u)})^3 dx$$

from where we get GENERAL SOLUTION

$$ x=3(u+ctg(u)) + c $$
$$ y=b(\cos{(u)})^3 , \quad u \in (0,\pi) .$$

My questions here are :

1.How i can correct Manipulate[Plot[],{b,0,10}] my Domain of d.e

2. How i can solve this equation using Mathematica, to get to my General Solution or atleast how to plot my finally General Solution which i get manually (but plot General Solution, not only one particular ).

Tnx.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10, x86, MMA -  11.3.0., your code Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[
  b^2 - 3 (b*y)^(2/3) (b^(2/3) - y^(2/3)) - y^2 > 0, {x, -3, 
   3}, {y, -3, 10}, Axes -> True], {b, 0, 10}]. Can you restart your kernel and try that again?

Comment: Tried on 11.2 and 11.3 , both only show that y going from 0 to b instead of -b to b

Comment: If we do, ff[x_, y_] := 
 Table[b^2 - 3 (b*y)^(2/3) (b^(2/3) - y^(2/3)) - y^2, {b, -10, 10, 1}]; ff[1, 1] // N (just an example to analyze why it fails). Do you see that this is generating imaginary roots and that is the issue?

Comment: yes, i see it give 

{124.354 + 68.0331 I, 101.591 + 59.8792 I, 81. + 51.9615 I, 
 62.5968 + 44.2967 I, 46.4012 + 36.9048 I, 32.4388 + 29.8101 I, 
 20.7446 + 23.0435 I, 11.37 + 16.6454 I, 4.39866 + 10.6709 I, 
 1.33227*10^-15 + 
  5.19615 I, -1., 0., 0.202677, 1.26001, 3.51071, 7.12241, 12.1976, \
18.8064, 27., 36.818, 48.2917}